# Is score-based reduced advertising really important?

Tags: discussion

Let's face it, the audience of these sites, is very tech-savvy and all probably using AdBlock either with Chrome or Firefox. We don't see any ads anyway, so you can't really offer us any less advertising that we already seeing with AdBlock

OK, let's the down vote race begin.

Comment: 1. What is your question? 2. Perhaps you're unaware that there are [quite a few](http://stackexchange.com/sites) non-computer-related Stack Exchange sites out there.

Comment: I was talking about computer related sites only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you're using adblock, why do you care?

Second, your whole premise is flawed.  Everyone uses adblock anyway, so they should stop reducing advertising?  That doesn't track.  Why not just turn them off?

Third, last I heard the sites were profitable.  *Somebody* must be viewing those ads and clicking on them and buying products that are relevant to their interests.  Let's hope they continue so the rest of us can all continue to enjoy a free resource like the bunch of blood-sucking leeches we are.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, they are doing effort to do [responsible advertisment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/) and when a site is putting effort in doing that, users tend to use less AdBlock. When people use AdBlock it's often because the ads are annoying. Here they ads aren't annoying. They are relevant and in bonus they do [advertisment for Open-Source project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/).

The difference between < 200 reputation and > 200 reputation, is that the ads you see are less in the way. This way we can still see some quality ads when we want to look at them and when we want to read question or answer, we don't have distraction.

Comment: The idea sounds great, but usually once you have AdBlock installed, it just does its thing - blocks ads on all sites unless you go and add edit settings, most people dont disable it even on sites that they generally like.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of traffic to the site are people from google trying to solve their problems.

Dropping ads for those with 200 rep who have bothered to sign in only loses a vanishingly small audience, and that audience still gets to see the sidebar ads, they simply aren't seeing the ads that break up the content.